# What is happening in the Ruby on Rails Authenticate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have been taking a deeper dive into the rails authenticate function

The actually implemnation seems to be very simply but there must be more magic happening. I'm hoping someone could explain the following results...

```
BCrypt::Password.new('$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q') == 'test1234567'
=> true

BCrypt::Password.new('$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q')
=> "$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q"

"$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q" == 'test1234567'
=> false
```

The password in the first statement is correct. It looks like it is evaluating the BCrypt::Password.new on the hashed password and comparing it to the given string.

To test this, I evaluated the BCrypt::Passowrd.new in the second statement, and then compared it the correct password in the third statement. This returns false... I tried escaping the forward slash but same result.

Can somone please explain whats happening here?

Here is a link to the implmentation of authenticate. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation/authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down statement by statement.

Your first statement is ok, it initializes a `BCrypt::Password` object and compares it to a string. `BCrypt::Password` implements the [comparison operator](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/BCrypt%2FPassword:==) which checks an object, in this case a string, against the temporary `BCrypt::Password` object.

In your second statement you are, like the first statement, initializing a `BCrypt::Password` object but aren't saving it to a variable, and the object goes unreferenced and unused. The output of the statement is simply the IRB returning the result of `.inspect` on the object.

Finally the third statement looks like you are comparing two unequal string and not any `BCrypt::Password` object.

To fix your second and third statement to work together you would want to do the following:

```
# Updated second statement
password = BCrypt::Password.new('$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q')
=> "$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q"

# Updated third statement
password == 'test1234567'
=> true
```

You can actually call `.inspect` on `password` yourself and you will see the result similar to what the IRB returned for the second statement.

```
password.inspect
=> "\"$2a$10$Pgxl1C8Ceg5WN5FJyP4OOOI/SiRZ0oujvWEWdNg95xp2qcPn6aP2q\""
```

Comment: Hey Mathew, Thanks for the response. I intentionally just printed out the result of BCrypt::Password in the second statement, and copy/pasted it for the third statement. I didn't realize what was being printed out was the `.inspect` function of the password object. Also another great point you made is that BCrypt::Password implements the comparison operator. That wasn't clear to me but makes sense why it would. Thanks again for the response